# Create duplicate rows in two data frames based on column values (pandas & numpy)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have two data frames, DF1 and DF2,

```
no1  quantity    no2
abc      3       123
pqr      5       NaN
```

and

```
no1    serial
abc      10
pqr      20
```

I want to create the following output DF3 and DF4

```
no1     quantity  
abc         3      
123         3      
pqr         5
```

and

```
no1       serial
abc         10
123         10
pqr         20
```

Kindly help to create DF3. I have thought about repeat the rows of Df1 if DF1['no1'] != 'NA' for Df3 then drop no2 column. It is possible to create DF4 by using `pd.merge` but the serial number of `123` should be `10` which is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For df3 you can use `append()` method,`to_frame()` method and `assign()` method:

```
df3=df1['no1'].append(df1['no2']).to_frame(name='no1').assign(quantity=df1['quantity']).reset_index(drop=True).dropna()
```

Output of `df3`:

```
    no1     quantity
0   abc     3
1   pqr     5
2   123.0   3
```

For df4 you can use `merge()` method ,`groupby()` method and `ffill()` method:

```
df4=df3.merge(df2,on='no1',how='left').groupby('quantity').ffill()
```

Output of `df4`:

```
    no1     serial
0   abc     10.0
1   pqr     20.0
2   123.0   10.0
```